# How to style XML displayed in HTML?

Tags: html, xml

I'd like to display XML pulled from a database on a website. I'd like to be able to style how it is displayed (such as different colors for string value, attributes, elements,..).

How would you do this? Can you use CSS? Thanks!

EDIT: I mean display the XML as XML editor would, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm interpreting your question to be about displaying the XML content as XML, but with pretty syntax highlighting, as you would get with an XML editor for example.)

I'd recommend [xmlverbatim](http://www2.informatik.hu-berlin.de/~obecker/XSLT/#xmlverbatim) via an XSLT transform (either server-side or via JavaScript). You can change its `indent-elements` parameter to control whether you want it to indent the XML.

For the XSLT transform on the client side, [xslt.js](http://johannburkard.de/software/xsltjs/) (possibly in conjunction with jQuery) should help.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. I edited the question :). I'll take a look at xmlverbatim!

Comment: Don't forget to include the CSS file provided if you want the pretty colours.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [XSL/XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).