# Display XML file inside Div

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to display an xml file inside a div, just like it opens in a browser(With colored tags,inner text & expand-collapse).Is it possible. For now, I am just displaying it in a label.

MY XML:

```
<EmployeeDetails>
  <Employee Uid="1546784553">
    <ID>100</ID>
    <Name>Pat</Name>
    <Salary>12000</Salary>
  </Employee>
   //....and so on
</EmployeeDetails>
```

ASPX:

```
<div id="divXml">
     <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
         <pre>
           <asp:Label ID="lblXml" runat="server" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
         </pre>
       </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnView" EventName="Click" />
      </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

CS:

```
private void ViewXml()
  {
    string strFile = Server.MapPath("~/XML/EmpXml.xml");
    if (File.Exists(strFile))
      { 
        string theXML = Server.HtmlEncode(File.ReadAllText
                         (Server.MapPath("~/XML/EmpXml.xml")));
        lblXml.Text = theXML;                 
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question looks to be similar to your question; perhaps it will answer your question?  [How to style XML displayed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451728/how-to-style-xml-displayed-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Look into [Google Code Pretifier](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) or [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Unfortunately there is no native code highlighting because the browser is not equipped to know syntax highlighting for any old language, you must use a plugin!

Comment: You are welcome!  Please mark any answers that may have helped you :)